# How do I prevent: raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp) HTTPError: Forbidden?

Tags: python, urllib2, http-error

I created the following definition:

```
def latent_similarity_index_fb(url):
    opener=urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor()) 
    soup=BeautifulSoup(opener.open(url).read(), "lxml")
return soup
```

However when I pass in a list urls, the following error is raised:

```
raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)  HTTPError: Forbidden?
```

How do I let the function continue reading list of urls?

Comment: `try` / `except`?

Comment: @KlausD. thanks, but I am a python newbie, care explaining how I should insert that into my definition?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html